# Prevent child element to use a parent class

Tags: css, inheritance, parent-child

I'm having an issue with this situation, I have a small form with one global class I use to track the state of the form, but now I have a checkbox which I don't want to inherit that parrent class... so how to prevent that?

```
<div id="find_employee" class="myCustomClass">
<div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="employee_last_name">Last Name</label>
                <input id="employee_last_name" name="employee_last_name" type="text" maxlength="30" class="form-control filterItem" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="employee_first_name">First Name</label>
                <input id="employee_first_name" name="employee_first_name" type="text" maxlength="30" class="form-control filterItem" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="employeeID">Employee ID #</label>
                <input id="employeeID" name="employeeID" type="text" maxlength="10" class="form-control filterItem" placeholder="Employee ID #">
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="checkbox" name="isActiveEmployee" id="isActiveEmployee" value="false" />
                <label for="isActiveEmployee">Include Inactive Employee</label>
            </div>
</div>
```

How to disable myCustomClass on the checkbox element on the bottom? Via js, jquery or css?

Comment: Overwrite the css-properties on the child element. Add your css and explain which properties you don't want active on the child.

Comment: how to tell my element to not have certain class?

Comment: What do you want to do differently for the checkbox? Which css-property you want overwritten? Do all of the fields even need to be inside "myCustomClass" div?

Comment: What you are looking is for removeClass??
$('#checkboxId').removeClass('myCustomClass');

Comment: I have this myCustomClass which is the parent class similar to a container class in bootstrap for example, now, I don't want my checkbox element to inherit that class also, but I can't move checkbox outside the parent div

Answer (score 0):

add a myCheckboxClass to checkbox and then use the not selector on myCustomClass

`myCustomClass: not(.mycheckboxClass) {
     ...
}`